# Can I quit during a performance review?

Tags: performance-reviews

I have a part time job.
I'm under a performance review.
I really hate working here.

Everyone is a mess.
The managers have no experience and don't see how this other manager is harassing me.

Comment: Why do you think there are times you can quit and times you can’t?  Is this really your question?

Comment: Are you a slave owned by the company or something? Why wouldn't you be able to quit?

Comment: Maybe it's their first job and they need some help with basic information. Gosh I wonder where on the internet they could go to ask questions about a workplace.

Comment: Are you searching for a new job?  If not, why not?

Comment: You can quit at any time. I quit during one of my disciplinary meetings around the company thinking my covid was fake. Bye have a great time. Idgaf about bridges but they probably are burned. I gave them notice. They kept me for a week, then let me go. Should've just left on the spot tbh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some places call what you are going through a "PIP" or performance improvement plan. They give you some goals, and a timeline, and maybe some other help; then when the time is up they make a decision about keeping you.

The big question is always: if I can quit, should I quit?

Quitting before you have to leave ends your stream of income. It can also impact your benefits.

Some people do survive a PIP. Many don't. Sometimes the PIP is a thing that management has to do before letting somebody go, and you have no chance of keeping your job.

Most people start the job search the same day they find out about the PIP. It starts a process they feel is inevitable. If they find a good job before the PIP ends they quit and move to the new job.

Normally quitting without notice burns bridges. But once they told you that you had a deadline, that served as notice that your job could be gone at the end of PIP. You leaving a few days before that doesn't shock anybody.

Comment: Im going through a pip. When i asked for specifics on dates they wouldn't tell me

Answer (score 10):

You can quit at any time, with or without notice. You'll burn a few bridges, but I don't see that you're too worried about that.

Comment: _"You can quit at any time, with or without notice."_ that depends on your contract and jurisdiction.

Comment: This is a VERY US centric view and NOT true everywhere.

Comment: @Hilmar 75% of the US anyway

Answer (score 3):

You can quit whenever your contract and your local labor laws say you can quit.

In an US at-will state, you can leave anytime without notice. However, that's not the case everywhere, so you I recommend checking your contract, employee handbook and local labor laws.

Comment: In an at-will state you can still have a contact that requires you give notice